# Меняется шрифт при удалении строки QTextView

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer, qss

Bсе работает нормально, единственное - в обоих полях `QTextView` размер курсора (вертикальной палки) меньше размера прозрачного текста `placeHolderText`.

При вводе, размер курсора нормализуется, однако **`если удалить все написанное`**, шрифт резко **`становится маленьким`** (после этого к нормальному размеру шрифта не возвращается).

Кто подскажет, с чем это может быть связано?

Код из *Qt Designer*:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("Encoder")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 606)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.button_decrypt = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button_decrypt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 250, 111, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.button_decrypt.setFont(font)
        self.button_decrypt.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor)
        self.button_decrypt.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"  background-color: rgb(215, 215, 215);\n"
"  border: 1px solid gray;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
"                                      stop: 0 #BEBEBE, stop: 1 #D7D7D7);\n"
"}")
        self.button_decrypt.setObjectName("button_decrypt")
        self.button_ecnrypt = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button_ecnrypt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 250, 111, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.button_ecnrypt.setFont(font)
        self.button_ecnrypt.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor)
        self.button_ecnrypt.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"  background-color: rgb(215, 215, 215);\n"
"  border: 1px solid gray;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
"                                      stop: 0 #BEBEBE, stop: 1 #D7D7D7);\n"
"}")
        self.button_ecnrypt.setObjectName("button_ecnrypt")
        self.text_to = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.text_to.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 781, 231))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.text_to.setFont(font)
        self.text_to.setProperty("cursor", QtCore.Qt.IBeamCursor)
        self.text_to.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.text_to.setObjectName("text_to")
        self.text_from = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.text_from.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 290, 781, 261))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.text_from.setFont(font)
        self.text_from.setProperty("cursor", QtCore.Qt.IBeamCursor)
        self.text_from.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.text_from.setObjectName("text_from")
        self.key_line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.key_line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(450, 250, 341, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.key_line.setFont(font)
        self.key_line.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.IBeamCursor)
        self.key_line.setObjectName("key_line")
        self.choise_box = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.choise_box.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 250, 191, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.choise_box.setFont(font)
        self.choise_box.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor)
        self.choise_box.setObjectName("choise_box")
        self.choise_box.addItem("")
        self.choise_box.addItem("")
        self.choise_box.addItem("")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, -1))
        self.button_decrypt.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Decrypt", None, -1))
        self.button_ecnrypt.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Encrypt", None, -1))
        self.text_to.setHtml(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML "
                                                                            "4.0//EN\" "
                                                                            "\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict"
                                                                            ".dtd\">\n "
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Consolas\'; font-size:16pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; "
                                                                            "-qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; "
                                                                            "font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; "
                                                                            "font-size:8.25pt;\"><br "
                                                                            "/></p></body></html>", None, -1))
        self.text_to.setPlaceholderText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "text", None, -1))
        self.text_from.setHtml(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD "
                                                                              "HTML 4.0//EN\" "
                                                                              "\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
                                                                              "/strict.dtd\">\n "
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Consolas\'; font-size:16pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; "
                                                                              "-qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; "
                                                                              "font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; "
                                                                              "font-size:8.25pt;\"><br "
                                                                              "/></p></body></html>", None, -1))
        self.text_from.setPlaceholderText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "text", None, -1))
        self.key_line.setPlaceholderText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "key", None, -1))
        self.choise_box.setItemText(0, QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Caesars code", None, -1))
        self.choise_box.setItemText(1, QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Gronsfeld code", None, -1))
        self.choise_box.setItemText(2, QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "test", None, -1))
```

**main.py**:

```py
from random import randint
import sys


class cryptoMain(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(cryptoMain, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = cryptoMain()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Hе указывал привязку кнопок, т.к. проблема только в окне текста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите строки:

```
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Consolas\'; font-size:16pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
```

я убрал в одном месте, почувствуйте разницу.

```
import sys
from random import randint

#from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("Encoder")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 606)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.button_decrypt = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button_decrypt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 250, 111, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.button_decrypt.setFont(font)
        self.button_decrypt.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor)
        self.button_decrypt.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"  background-color: rgb(215, 215, 215);\n"
"  border: 1px solid gray;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
"                                      stop: 0 #BEBEBE, stop: 1 #D7D7D7);\n"
"}")
        self.button_decrypt.setObjectName("button_decrypt")
        self.button_ecnrypt = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button_ecnrypt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 250, 111, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.button_ecnrypt.setFont(font)
        self.button_ecnrypt.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor)
        self.button_ecnrypt.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"  background-color: rgb(215, 215, 215);\n"
"  border: 1px solid gray;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,\n"
"                                      stop: 0 #BEBEBE, stop: 1 #D7D7D7);\n"
"}")
        self.button_ecnrypt.setObjectName("button_ecnrypt")

        self.text_to = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.text_to.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 781, 231))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.text_to.setFont(font)
        self.text_to.setProperty("cursor", QtCore.Qt.IBeamCursor)
        self.text_to.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.text_to.setObjectName("text_to")


        self.text_from = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.text_from.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 290, 781, 261))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.text_from.setFont(font)
        self.text_from.setProperty("cursor", QtCore.Qt.IBeamCursor)
        self.text_from.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.text_from.setObjectName("text_from")

        self.key_line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.key_line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(450, 250, 341, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.key_line.setFont(font)
        self.key_line.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.IBeamCursor)
        self.key_line.setObjectName("key_line")
        self.choise_box = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.choise_box.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 250, 191, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.choise_box.setFont(font)
        self.choise_box.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor)
        self.choise_box.setObjectName("choise_box")
        self.choise_box.addItem("")
        self.choise_box.addItem("")
        self.choise_box.addItem("")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, -1))
        self.button_decrypt.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Decrypt", None, -1))
        self.button_ecnrypt.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Encrypt", None, -1))
        self.text_to.setHtml(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML "
                                                                            "4.0//EN\" "
                                                                            "\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict"
                                                                            ".dtd\">\n "
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"

# Это убираем !!!
#"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Consolas\'; font-size:16pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"

"<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; "
                                                                            "-qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; "
                                                                            "font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; "
                                                                            "font-size:8.25pt;\"><br "
                                                                            "/></p></body></html>", None, -1))
        self.text_to.setPlaceholderText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "text", None, -1))
        self.text_from.setHtml(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD "
                                                                              "HTML 4.0//EN\" "
                                                                              "\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
                                                                              "/strict.dtd\">\n "
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Consolas\'; font-size:16pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; "
                                                                              "-qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; "
                                                                              "font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; "
                                                                              "font-size:8.25pt;\"><br "
                                                                              "/></p></body></html>", None, -1))
        self.text_from.setPlaceholderText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "text", None, -1))
        self.key_line.setPlaceholderText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "key", None, -1))
        self.choise_box.setItemText(0, QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Caesars code", None, -1))
        self.choise_box.setItemText(1, QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Gronsfeld code", None, -1))
        self.choise_box.setItemText(2, QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "test", None, -1))



class cryptoMain(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(cryptoMain, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = cryptoMain()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в них было какое то несоответствие? или почему так было?